# Is MVC the only acceptable way to develop a desktop application with a GUI?

Tags: java, model-view-controller

Or are there other generally accepted patterns for creating a generic business application with a graphical interface and no network connectivity.

Comment: Games are very different for other programs.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2105121/what-to-use-mvc-mvp-or-mvvm-or , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977317/mvc-mvp-mvvm-frameworks-for-java-gui-applications ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another similar pattern that fully separates the layers, [n-tier architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture) though very similar is easier to understand and once you manage to separate the logic it makes the hardware separation easier if you would like to further extend it.

Answer (score 1):

I use the [Observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) quite a bit. A similar example in the wild is [RCP's selection service](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-WorkbenchSelections/article.html).

Answer (score 1):

It isn't the only acceptable way, but the concepts in an MVC design will provide you with a good foundation. The Computer Science community has built these design patterns because of the years and decades we have developing applications. After dealing with the same problems over and over, we've built up these design patterns to avoid the problems in future development.

If you don't want to follow these design patterns, you can.... but you're setting yourself up for pain. There isn't a good reason to reinvent the wheel. It's better to take a cue from all of the developers who came before you. :)